# RuntimeError when changing the values of specific parts of a `torch.Tensor`

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

Say I have a 3 dimentional tensor `x` initialized with zeros:

```
x = torch.zeros((2, 2, 2))
```

and an other 3 dimentional tensor `y`

```
y = torch.ones((2, 1, 2))
```

I am trying to change the values of the first line of `x[0]` and `x[1]` like this

```
x[:, 0, :] = y
```

but I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: expand(torch.FloatTensor{[2, 1, 2]}, size=[2, 2]): the number of sizes provided (2) must be greater or equal to the number of dimensions in the tensor (3)
```

It is as if the tensor `y` was getting squeezed somehow.  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a straight forward way to do it:

```
x[:, 0, :] = y[:, 0, :]
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
x = torch.arange(0, 8).reshape((2,2,2))
y = torch.ones((2,2))
x2 = x.permute(1,0,2)
x2[0] = y
x_target = x2.permute(1,0,2)
```

The value of first rows of `x` are changed by `y` .

Comment: Thanks, your solution works, but it is not as straight forward as the one I found, so I won't accept it.